# Command for WinRAR on specific file

Tags: java, cmd, runtime, winrar

I have a code to archive a ZIP file into another ZIP file, using command like this:

```
String rootftp = "C:\\ROOT_DIR_PUSHFILE\\";
    String tampungString = "AAA\\PFILE\\AAA20140531.zip";
    String password = "testing";

    String command = "cmd.exe "
            + "/C"
            + " cd C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR \n"
            +" && rar a -n "+rootftp.trim()+tampungString+".zip"+" "+ rootftp.trim()+tampungString + " -p"+password.trim();
    System.out.println(command);

    File file = new File(rootftp.trim()+tampungString);
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But the result is :

[image]

When I try to archive a specific file, the results is always archive from root directory, not just the specific file, like AAA20140531.zip file, can you explain, why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Do you know that console version `Rar.exe` supports only compressing and extracting RAR archives? So even with `.zip` specified on command line, the created archive file is nevertheless a RAR archive and not a ZIP archive. Read introduction at top of file `Rar.txt` in program files folder of WinRAR. Only GUI version `WinRAR.exe` supports ZIP compression / extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this command to create `.rar` without parent folder:

```
rar a -ep1 c:\ROOT_DIR_PUSHFILE\AAA\PFILE\AAA20140531.zip c:\ROOT_DIR_PUSHFILE\AAA\PFILE\ -p123456
```

`-ep1` switch makes the result to exclude the base folder from the paths,

Comment: Would you please accept the question if you have the results you want